# How to place sprites onto rect object in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, game-engine, game-physics

I was wondering if any of you knew how to attach a sprite to a rect object I already made in pygame?

Here's my code:

```
blocktexture1 = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
blocktexture1.rect = self.platforms
for block in self.platforms:
   pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, block, 0)
```

I don't understand which rectangle to apply the sprite rect thing to!

Answer (score 0):

Assign your sprite's `rect` attribute to the Rectangle you made. For example:

```
example_sprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
example_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)
example_sprite.rect = example_rect
```

Comment: You're going to have to give me more code than that. Is self.platforms a list of rectangles?

Comment: Yeah, the code is part of a function in a world building class. It takes input from a text file, where a "-" is a platform.

Comment: So, you want each rectangle to have it's own sprite? Then you need to create a new list, `sprites`, and make an individual sprite for each platform.

Comment: Then loop through the sprites / rects and assign each rect to its own Sprite. I suggest you look at [my personal Map Loading System.](https://github.com/superman3275/Hooded/blob/master/Hooded/Hooded/Map/map.py)

Comment: But I still don't understand how to apply the sprites... which Rect object would I apply them to?

Comment: Looks like you need a tutorial, sir, follow a pygame tutorial with sprites first and this will answer your questions.

Comment: You don't apply the sprites to the rects, you apply the rects to the sprites. [Just read this.](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/SpriteIntro.html)